# Sitefinity no caching

Tags: sitefinity

I am setting the page caching options to no caching. When I run the page why am I not seeing the meta `Cache-Control: no-cache`. Is there another setting I need to use for this page not to cache?

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be if there is a device (e.g. WAF, CDN, etc.) in front of the server, that has its own caching rules that override the caching headers produced by Sitefinity.

If that's the case, check the origin url (or local instance if possible) and see if you get the same result.